# Read all type(format) offiles in Node js

Tags: node.js, file, node-modules

I would like to read maximum file types in nodejs using single module. I have used "textract" but it is not able to read all pdf, nor it is reading rtf files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the required programs: pdftotext and unrtf for PDF and RTF support.

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/textract#extraction-requirements

Comment: I'm not able to found pdftotext. And how to use this in my code?

Comment: `pdftotext` is provided by `poppler`.